# Speeding up SQL query with more than 6 billion operations

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have a Django project with the following problem:

`User` objects are stored in the `auth_user` table

These have a One-to-One relation to the `Profile` object, this object is stored in the `yuza_profile` table. Its relation to the `user` is maintained through the `user_id` field

However, years ago thousands of `Profile` objects were deleted without removing the linked `User` objects.

These users without profiles are causing problems in our system and we would like to remove them.

I created the following SQL query to perform this task

```
DELETE FROM auth_user WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM yuza_profile);
```

Since the `Profile` objects have been deleted I cannot scan for `null` values on `*_id` fields - which would be my first move here.

Instead I am looping over two tables that both contain more than 60.000 rows which leads to a slow and inefficient query with more than 6 billion operations (and server timeouts)

Is there a way to speed up this query? I am aware that my query is very inefficient but I do not know of a way to improve it and any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: As requested I've included the schemas below:

```
user_profile

id - integer
user_id - integer
gender - varchar(2)
birth_date - date
address - varchar(255)
city - varchar(255)
phone_number - varchar(10)
avatar - varchar(255)
---------------------
user_profile_pkey - (id)
user_profile_user_id_key - (user_id)
user_profile_user_id_fkey - (user_id) -> auth_user(id)
user_profile_pkey - (id) UNIQUE
user_profile_user_id_key - (user_id) UNIQUE
```

```
auth_user

id - integer
username - varchar(150)
first_name - varchar(30)
last_name - varchar(30)
email - varchar(75)
password - varchar(128)
is_staff - boolean
is_active - boolean
is_superuser - boolean
last_login - timestamp with time zone
date_joined - timestamp with time zone
---------------
auth_user_pkey - (id)
auth_user_username_key - (username)
auth_user_pkey - (id) UNIQUE
auth_user_username_key - (username) UNIQUE
```

I should note that I've started to wonder if the IDE (PycharmPro) I am using might be a factor - when testing my queries with the `SELECT` statement the IDE displays queryresults as pages with 500 results per page. The initial query indeed took less than a second - but pressing the 'go to last page' button took more than 2 minutes (for just 16000 results)

Comment: 60K rows is *no data at all*. That amount probably fits in the CPU's cache. Post the table schemas (including any indexes) and the execution plans. Most likely `yuza_profile.user_id` and `auth_user.id` aren't covered by indexes. Lots of data is billions of rows and TBs of data

Comment: As for 6Bn operations, that would only happen if there were no indexes and the server had to run a full table scan of the inner table for every row in the outer table. Another possibility is that `id` and `user_id` have different types or different collations which would require a conversion from one type to the other before comparison. In that case, any indexes created using the original type are useless

Comment: very often `not exists` performs better than `not in`. Did you try to rewrite that query? `DELETE FROM auth_user WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM yuza_profile p WHERE p.user_id = auth_user.id); `

Comment: I wonder if the IDE (PycharmPro) I am using might be a factor - its show database queryresults as pages with 500 results per page. THe initial query indeed took less than a second - but pressing the 'go to last page' button took 2 min.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I tried your solution and loading the 'last page' took less than a second, thanks!

Comment: A DELETE statement has no "result"

Comment: My apologies - I had just tested your code with a SELECT statement when I wrote my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly advise you to use `NOT EXISTS` rather than `NOT IN`.  It treats `NULL` values more intuitively.  (`NOT IN` will filter out *all rows* if *any* value in the subquery is `NULL`.)

So, write the query as:

```
DELETE au FROM auth_user au
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM yuza_profile vp 
                      WHERE vp.user_id = au.id
                     );
```

This query can take advantage of an index on `yuza_profile(user_id)`:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_yuza_profile_user_id ON yuza_profile(user_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure about your approach, I'm assuming you took a cursor-based strategy, but can't you just:

```
DELETE FROM auth_user WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM yuza_profile);
```

If you have the proper indices, this DML instruction will not require that much operations.

Comment: That's exactly the statement that is show in the question

Comment: I edited it! I initially showed a SELECT statement that I left in by error